# How to extract data from a Maxtor Shared Storage II backup

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, nas

I am just trying to salvage data from my dying Maxtor Shared Storage II enclosure. I have backed it up to an external USB drive using its onboard features and would like to restore it to a different location, using an ordinary Linux machine.

The backup disk is formatted with an ext3 filesystem, which Linux can mount. The backup seems to reside in a directory tree, with one XML file holding metadata and an archive apparently holding my backed-up data.

The archive file has a .tar.gz extension, but when I try to open it, I get an error message saying the file is not a valid gzip-compressed file. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `file` on the archive gives:

`POSIX tar archive (GNU)`

So, apparently the MSS II creates regular tar archives but gives them a .gz extension, despite not compressing them. After renaming it from `.tar.gz` tp `.tar` I was able to extract its contents.

YMMV – if this doesn't work for someone, run `file` on the archive to find out if and how it was compressed, then rename it giving it the correct extension.